# Python - zipping and list

Tags: python, list, zip

I just started coding python a couple weeks ago and getting my hands dirty. However I am not being able to get past the problem with zipping and list.

here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df_reader = pd.read_csv('Indicators.csv', chunksize=1000)

df_urb_pop = next(df_reader)

df_pop_ceb = df_urb_pop[df_urb_pop['CountryCode']=='CEB']

zipped = zip(df_pop_ceb['Population, total'], df_pop_ceb['Urban population (% of total)'])

pops_list = list(zipped)

print(pops_list)
```

this is the error ive been getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 2134, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4433)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4279)
  File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 732, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13742)
  File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13696)
KeyError: 'Population, total'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mubashirsultan/PycharmProjects/TECH6360/Iterators practice.py", line 9, in <module>
    zipped = zip(df_pop_ceb['Population, total'], df_pop_ceb['Urban population (% of total)'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2059, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2066, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1386, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3543, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 2136, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4433)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4279)
  File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 732, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13742)
  File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13696)
KeyError: 'Population, total'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Not quite sure what mistake ive made. a little help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: `df_pop_ceb` is a dictionary presumably, and it does not have a key called `'Population, total'`.

Comment: it does within the csv file.

Comment: Before you call `df_pop_ceb['Population, total']`, I would `print(df_pop_ceb.keys())` Then you can see what keys are actually in the dict. You may need to add the key(s) in a different way. It's hard to know without being able to test with the same csv file.

Comment: the csv file i got from is here: https://www.kaggle.com/worldbank/world-development-indicators (indicators.csv)

and ill try that thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have download the `Indicators.csv` from the link you provided, the header of the csv file only contain this keys:

```
import pandas as pd
df_reader = pd.read_csv('Indicators.csv')
df_reader.keys()
```

Output:

```
Index([u'CountryName', u'CountryCode', u'IndicatorName', u'IndicatorCode',
       u'Year', u'Value'],
      dtype='object')
```

There is no key '`Population, total`' and '`Urban population (% of total)`', probably you used wrong data source (csv file).